# How to keep input value in sidebar on route change in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a sidebar as parent and two component that I want to show in `<router-outlet>` as child. I have an input inside sidebar, and I want to keep the value when I change the route. something like angular website search input.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bizgdk)

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Which value do you want to keep and where? Do you want to show the route value in the input?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running into this Angular bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18374

Due to this bug, even if you are only changing the child route, the parent components are destroyed and recreated.

There is a workaround posted where a user has created a generic `RouteReuseStrategy` that can be used to indicate which parent routes should be saved.  Using that workaround I have fixed your Stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rmr1q

Comment: only the url changes, but the page remains unchang.